# Starting with IntelliJ and Gradle : how to do jUnit tests?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Good evening,

because I want to initiate myself to LibGDX, I recently gave a try to IntelliJ Idea IDE and Gradle instead of my old Eclipse-Maven habits.

I have to recognize that such a change is not easy because I really don't find anything.

To start learning I created a project with a simple Pojo and also a unit test class.

[image]

I have no error in the editor, both Pojo and jUnit seem OK, but when I launch the unit test, I get such errors :

[image]

Can someone help me understand what's going wrong ?

EDIT : build.gradle file content :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.citizenweb.training'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.16'

}
```

Thanx by advance.

Comment: you are using `lombok` library: how did you declare `lombok` related dependencies?  could you share your `build.gradle` so that man can help you?  also, did you enable "annotation processor" option in IDEA?  this is mandatory when using libraries like lombok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you did not configure `lombok` dependencies properly: your test classes cannot see lombok-generated stuff (getters, setters, build). Lombok is based on annotation processor so you need to declare following dependencies in your `build.gradle` :

```
ext {
    lombokVersion = "1.18.6"
}

    dependencies {
        
        // Lombok
        compileOnly ("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")
        annotationProcessor ("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")
    
        // to make lombok available for test classes
        testCompileOnly ("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")
        testAnnotationProcessor ("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")

        testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
    }
```

Comment: Evening, thx for answering me. You surely are right about my 'build.gradle' file.
May I ask why 'testImplementation' is related to Spring ?

Comment: You're right there was a mistake in my example (copy/paste from other project), there is nothing related to Spring here; I added missing dependency in the example : `testCompileOnly ("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")`